# Javascript performance in UIWebView not in current ViewController running iOS 8

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently developing a hybrid HTML/Native app with Apache Cordova for iOS and Android. For this app I'm using a UINavigationController as I wanted to be able to use the swipe to go back function made available in iOS 7. In my initial ViewController I do create some other native controls and thus some of the JS-code interacting with those controls runs in this controller.

One of those controls is a UITableView in it's own ViewController. I push the ViewController to my UINavigationController immediately while I wait for my data to load from a remote server, or from my local database.

When loading from my local database I noticed that it took nearly 2 seconds for the results to be loaded into the UITableView on my device running iOS 8 (an iPhone 6). I then tested the same thing in the simulator running iOS 8 and the same delay appeared. Testing with iOS 7 in the simulator yielded no delay at all.

This morning I decided to figure out why the code ran so much slower in iOS 8 than it does in iOS 7. Verifying that it wasn't just my code that the problem I ran the sample code from this plugin: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin and got the same result.

Figuring it was something else in my code causing the slowness I decided to set up a new project running only the sample code above and it executed quickly in both iOS 7 and 8, so the problem must have been somewhere in my code. I gradually began adding bits and pieces of my original project to the new one until the code slowed down.

It wasn't until I had restored all the code that I noticed that the code only ran slowly in certain parts of the app. If the Javascript was excuted in the current view controller it ran fine, but once it ran in a background controller it became slow.

Knowing why the code was slow made fixing it quite easy. All I had to do was stick a Cordova UIWebView in the same view controller as my UITableView and get it to trigger the Javascript once loaded.

Does anyone know why Javascript executes more slowly if run from a background view controller in iOS 8? I know Apple made some changes to the UIWebView in iOS 8 and introduced the WKWebView as well, but I haven't seen anything that would indicate why performance was degraded in background view controllers.